# Exibir atributo manufacture no frontend Magento

Tags: magento, front-end, atributos, phtml

Trabalho com o **Magento** a pouco tempo e também não tenho lá muito conhecimento ainda e meu caso é o seguinte: na lista de exibição dos itens gostaria de exibir o atributo `manufacture` do item.

Usei o seguinte código no `list.phtm`:

```
<?php
    echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getManufacturer() , 'manufacturer');
?>
```

Porém ele exibe para mim o **ID** e não o nome.

Comment: Experimente `$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')`

Comment: Funcionou lindamente e pelo que vejo posso usar isto para qualquer atributo agora somente fazendo uma pequena alteração. Obrigado